# Declare protocol function with default argument values

Tags: swift, callback, option-type, swift-protocols, completion

I want this function be in protocol:

```
func slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((Bool)->())? = nil) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

But when I write such protocol:

```
protocol SomeDelegate { 
    func slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((Bool)->())? = nil) 
}
```

I got an error:

> Default argument not permitted in a protocol method

I know, I can define the signature in this way:

```
protocol SomeDelegate { 
    func slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((Bool)->())?) 
}
```

But then, I won't be able to call the function missing "completion" word:

```
slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: vc)
```

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately optional arguments are not allowed in protocols, but you can work around this by creating an extension of the protocol:

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
    // with the completion parameter
    func slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((Bool)->())?)
}

extension SomeDelegate {
    // without the completion parameter
    func slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        slideToRight(slideToRight(currentViewController: viewController, completion: nil))
    }
}
```

Comment: OP can add the default value when implementing the method. It is not allowed only in the protocol definition

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah, but when you call the method on a protocol type, you still have to add the parameter. I think this is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: You didn't get it `extension SomeDelegate {
    func slideToRight(currentViewController viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((Bool)->())? = nil) {
        // code
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus That kind of loses the point of the protocol doesn't it? You are not forced to implement method in that case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the point of the protocol thats how OP needs to implement a default value. Btw it would be much better to extend UIViewController instead of passing it as a parameter `extension SomeDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func slideToRight(completion: ((Bool)->())? = nil) {
       
    }
}`

Comment: `Unfortunately optional arguments are not allowed in protocols` ??? It is allowed and if you define it as optional you need to implement it as optional to conform to the protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus What do you mean by "???". According to here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html "Default values, however, can’t be specified for method parameters within a protocol’s definition."

Comment: Talking about optional parameter. Btw No need to define a parameter as optional to set a default value other than nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166262/discussion-between-sweeper-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Great idea! Just changed my code, compiled and ran right away.